# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis !! im trying to create tables, should i add a foreign key?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE brunch      
(
    br_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    br_name INT NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE employee 
(
    e_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    bdate DATE,
    fname VARCHAR2(30),
    lname VARCHAR2(30),
    sal NUMBER,
    sex VARCHAR2(1),
    address VARCHAR2(50),
    super_id INT REFERENCES employee(e_id) 
)

ALTER TABLE brunch ADD mgr_id int REFERENCES employee(e_Id);

ALTER TABLE employee ADD b_id INT REFERENCES brunch(br_id);

CREATE TABLE client
(
    c_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    c_name VARCHAR2(40),
    c_oemail VARCHAR2(40),
    c_email VARCHAR2(40),
    b_id reference brunch(b_id) 
)
```

The problem is with the last table, table client, and it give me an error message that says

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

but I don't see any problem with the syntax. Thank you

Comment: b_id is a column on employee table, not brunch.

Answer (score 0):

The last `DDL` should be

```
create table client
(
 c_id     int  primary key,
 c_name   varchar2(40),
 c_oemail varchar2(40),
 c_email  varchar2(40),
 b_id references brunch(br_id) 
);
```

- where column name `b_id` should be `br_id` and
- there's no keyword called `reference` but `references`

P.S. There's no need to use `NOT NULL` for a column defined as `PRIMARY KEY`(already includes `NOT NULL`).